# React-native put values in state with fetch in a loop

Tags: loops, asynchronous, react-native, fetch, state

I want to get duration of few journeys with the google API but I can't put values obtained in my state.
This is my code :

```
for (i = 0; i < this.state.nbLieux; i++) {
        const index = i;
        fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&mode=walking&origins=${this.state.location.coords.latitude},${this.state.location.coords.longitude}&destinations=${this.state.lieux[index].lattitude},${this.state.lieux[index].longitude}&key=AIzaSyBqonK_W7A4chMiVoJTTs2cTU65XBcCh68`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            Duree[index] = responseJson.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error);
        })
        .done();
    }
    this.setState({Duree});
    console.log('salut'+JSON.stringify(this.state.Duree));
```

Thanks !

EDIT

```
this.myFunction().then((Duree) => { 
            console.log(Duree)
        });

myFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fetches = [];
        let Duree = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.nbLieux; i++) {
            fetches.push(
                fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&mode=walking&origins=${this.state.location.coords.latitude},${this.state.location.coords.longitude}&destinations=${this.state.lieux[i].lattitude},${this.state.lieux[i].longitude}&key=AIzaSyBqonK_W7A4chMiVoJTTs2cTU65XBcCh68`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                    Duree[i] = responseJson;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.warn(error);
                }).done()
            )
        }
        Promise.all(fetches).then(() => {
            resolve(Duree);
        })
    });
}
```

But in the console I can see that the first console.log is execute before the second in the fetch...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a Promise and use the LET keyword for es6 or closure for es5. Like so...

```
    myFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let fetches = [];
      let arr = [];

      for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        fetches.push(
            fetch("https://slack.com/api/api.test")
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((dataJson) => {
          arr[i] = dataJson;
        })
        )
      }

      Promise.all(fetches).then(() => {
        resolve(arr);
      })

    });
   }

   myFunction().then((data) => {
       console.log(data);
   })
```

Tested a works just fine. This is the console.log in Chrome...

[image]

Also, make sure the state of "nbLieux" isn't changing. If it is, use another let variable right above the for loop: "let num = this.state.nbLieux"

Comment: Hi VocoJax, thanks for your answer, I tried your code but a got an ampty array in the state. Look my Edit to see what I tried.

Comment: I edited my answer. It hasn't changed at all, but I have tested it and it works. Is your api string broken perhaps?